# Baltimore - Which areas are the safest?

Tags: usa, safety, rental, event-based-effects, baltimore

I will be travelling to Baltimore and planned to stay there for almost 2 months (will be working at hospital there).

Which areas are the safest and well connected to Johns Hopkins Hospital?

Comment: I've edited your question to avoid being too specific, and to hopefully help others who might be looking for the topic as well.  Also to avoid close votes (although short term in this case, people often close vote what appears to be a moving/expat question)

Comment: What is `safe` to you?

Comment: @chx he said _safest_. It's all relative ;)

Comment: They don't discuss how safe they are, but the hospital has a whole "moving to Baltimore" site. Here's the subpage on neighborhoods: http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/about/baltimore/moving/choosing_place_live/neighborhoods.html

Comment: Going to some place to work, how is this not [expatriates.se]?

Comment: @Gccampbell - because it's only for 2 months?

Answer (score 2):

As, presumably, this can change from year to year, and also depend on the types of crime you're concerned about, it'd be useful to see maps of crime in the various suburbs and neighbourhoods of the city.  Therefore:

- [Crime Baltimore](http://crimebaltimore.com/) - part of SpotCrime, shows where particular crime events and types occurred. Interesting but doesn't compare suburbs.
- [Neighbourhood Scout](http://www.neighborhoodscout.com/md/baltimore/crime/) shows the various neighbourhoods, indicating crime level by colour. This is probably the easiest view of the most crime-ridden areas, although you'll need to click through to see and distinguish the types of crimes that occurred.
  -

Comment: What about fires and traffic incidents?

Comment: @CMaster what about meteor strikes or flash floods? For some reason in my experience, people asking about safety never seen to wonder about fires or traffic crashes - it's the crime that concerns them (expats at least).  Shrug.  Probably also reflects why those sites choose these stats as well.

Comment: Those examples seem relativley unlikley to effect overall risk levels. Incidents with traffic are probably the biggest threat to life and health, so given no mention of criminal activity by the OP, seems relevant to address.

Comment: Worth noting that Neighbourhood Scout seems to release detailed information only with a paid subscription.